# Xamarin - Updating listview items as data is received

Tags: xamarin

I have a `Listview` that requires two API calls, one for all the text data, and one for image data for each item (via byte array). I first get all the text data and show the list, with a placeholder image. I then do a loop over all the items in the list view, and for each item I retrieve its image. I'd like the `Listview` to update after each image is retrieved, so that slowly the images will populate down the list, 1 by 1. However, the `Listview` only updates as `Listview` items are shown for the first time. For example, I'll load 20 items, with 7 being shown (the rest need to be scrolled to). If I wait a few seconds and scroll, the 8th+ items will show the updated images. Once all 20 items have retrieved their image, the entire list will update and show all the images.

I've tried setting the `ItemSource` (`Results`) of the listview to null after each image is retrieved, which calls `OnPropertyChanged()`, however the list still doesn't update for each item. Here's the code:

```
public async Task GetImagesForResults()
           {
             using (var scope = App.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
             {
                    using (new Busy(this))
                   {

                    var peopleService = scope.Resolve<IPersonService>();
                    _incompleteResults = Results;

                    if (_incompleteResults != null && _incompleteResults.Count > 0)
                    {

                        foreach(PersonViewModel p in _incompleteResults)
                        {
                            if (StopLoading)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            IsBusy = false;
                            var peopleImage = await peopleService.GetPersonImage(p.Email);
                            if ((peopleImage.Error == null) && (peopleImage.Response != null))
                            {
                                p.Picture = peopleImage.Response;

                                p.PictureImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(peopleImage.Response));
                                p.ShowInitials = false;
                                Results = null;
                                Results = _incompleteResults;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: does PersonViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and is it firing the PropertyChanged event when PictureImageSource is updated?

Comment: I had implemented INotifyPropertyChanged but forgot to include the PropertyChanged event in the PictureImageSource property! This fixed it, thanks a ton.